# Detailed guide on using gcov with CMake/CDash?

Tags: c++, testing, cmake, code-coverage, cdash

I'm using CMake with my project and set up a cdash server for continuous/nightly building. Everything works well and by setting up a crontab, we have hourly/nightly build/test results uploaded to our cdash server automatically.

My next step is to add test coverage report to the build. I find the document here https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/-/wikis/doc/ctest/Coverage but frankly it's a bit far from a practical guide.

Currently I've added the required flag (instead of `-fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage`, I find `--coverage` better), the compilation process generates .gcno files. But then I'm stuck. The command

```
make NightlyCoverage
```

doesn't seem to do anything. Could anybody tell me what is the next to do? The result that I want, is by doing `make NightlyCoverage`, coverage reports are generated and uploaded to cdash server.

Comment: The link seems broken.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

I've been using https://github.com/bilke/cmake-modules/blob/master/CodeCoverage.cmake successfully.

Just followed the guidelines: added the files to my `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH` directory, added

```
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/CMakeModules)
if(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX)
    include(CodeCoverage)
    setup_target_for_coverage(${PROJECT_NAME}_coverage ${PROJECT_TEST_NAME} coverage)
endif()
```

in my `CMakeLists.txt`. I also added manually `gcov` as a dependency for my target:

```
if(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX)
    target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_TEST_NAME} gcov)
endif()
```

With this, I just type

```
make my_project_coverage
```

and I get the html report in the `coverage` directory of my build tree.

Comment: Linking to gcov isn't really necessary. Gcc does that automatically anyway, and it will not work with Clang for instance which instead should link againt libprofile_rt

Comment: I'll add a note that I'm using clang on OSX and besides a warning in CodeCoverage.cmake, this solution worked perfectly.

Comment: @rcomblen Will that aggregate the coverage results for all of your tests? Or do you need to setup_target_for_coverage for every test target?

Comment: Can one exclude directories using this approach? I don't see any options in the tool itself.

Comment: You can add exclusion rules in the `CodeCoverage.cmake`file (or pass it via a variable), set line 145, the `--remove` option of lcov.

Comment: How does one set a custom gcov version using this plugin?

Comment: @sholsapp My first guess would be to set the `GCOV_PATH` variable. See line 71 of https://github.com/bilke/cmake-modules/blob/master/CodeCoverage.cmake

Comment: How come `make my_project_coverage` works? `CodeCoverage.cmake` adds a custom target, but in my experience those are only put in subdir makefiles which is very inconvenient... Is there a trick you can share?

Comment: Clang support was added to CodeCoverage.cmake on 2013-09-17!

Comment: The line regarding ``setup_target_for_coverage`` is incorrect; it should be ``setup_target_for_coverage(NAME ${PROJECT_NAME} ....``; (I've edited the answer, but it was rejected).

Comment: Anybody has a recent example github project that I can take a look at? As @PhilippLudwig said, I am not sure if the above answer is correct anymore.

Comment: Can this be adapted for clang?

Comment: Also - this doesn't work for me. The modules says "  Compiler is not GNU gcc! Aborting..." - even though I'm using GCC.

Comment: @einpoklum The current code specifically checks that `CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX` — IOW, it wants to see `g++` enabled. If you have a C-only project, you might consider adjusting that, or you can add CXX to your project `LANGUAGES`.

Answer (score 12):

I use `gcovr` to make a **GCC Code Coverage Report** without the `CodeCoverage.cmake` :

```
$ cd /path/to/your/project
$ mkdir build && cd build && cmake ..
$ make && make test
$ gcovr -r ../ .
```

Comment: I know that this is in the documentation however I found it pretty handy `gcovr -r . --html --html-details -o example-html-details.html`

Comment: I kept getting failure by `-r .` until I found your command is `-r .. .` !

Answer (score 11):

This answer is the same as @rcomblen's answer but its a bit outdated so I'll share my solution. Here's what I did:

1. created a toy project

```
(base) ciaran@DESKTOP-K0APGUV:/mnt/d/CoverageTest$ tree -L 2
.
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── cmake
│   └── CodeCoverage.cmake
├── src
│   ├── domath.cpp
│   ├── domath.h
│   └── testdomath.cpp
└── third_party
    └── googletest
```

Where

```
// src/domath.h

#ifndef COVERAGETEST_DOMATH_H
#define COVERAGETEST_DOMATH_H


class domath {

public:
    int add(int a, int b);
};


#endif //COVERAGETEST_DOMATH_H
```

and

```
// src/domath.cpp

#include "domath.h"

int domath::add(int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
}
```

and

```
// src/testdomath.cpp
#include "gtest/gtest.h"
#include "domath.h"


TEST(DoMathTests, testAdd){
    domath m;
    int actual = m.add(4, 6);
    ASSERT_EQ(10, actual);
}
```

2. download googletest and put it under third party directory
3. copy the [gist](https://gist.github.com/oneamtu/3734295) so kindly shared by the other answers on this thread into `cmake/CodeCoverage.cmake`
4. install `gcovr`. This step is vital, because the other answers on this thread no longer work with the version of `gcovr` that I already had:

```
(base) ciaran@DESKTOP-K0APGUV:/mnt/d/CoverageTest$ pip install gcovr
(base) ciaran@DESKTOP-K0APGUV:/mnt/d/CoverageTest$ gcovr --version
gcovr 4.2
(base) ciaran@DESKTOP-K0APGUV:/mnt/d/CoverageTest$ which gcovr
/home/ciaran/miniconda3/bin/gcovr
```

Note, we need the output of which `gcovr` for the cmake script.
4) Write a cmake script that create a library, a test executable and use the `CodeCoverage.cmake` module:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)
project(CoverageTest)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

# setup googletest
add_subdirectory(third_party/googletest)

# create our library
add_library(DoMath STATIC src/domath.h src/domath.cpp)
add_dependencies(DoMath gtest gtest_main)

# create the test executable
add_executable(TestDoMath src/testdomath.cpp)
target_include_directories(TestDoMath PRIVATE third_party/googletest/googletest)
target_link_libraries(TestDoMath PRIVATE
        DoMath gtest gtest_main)
add_dependencies(TestDoMath DoMath gtest gtest_main)

# now for coverage bits
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake)
if (CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX)
    include(CodeCoverage)
    append_coverage_compiler_flags()

    # we need to turn off optimization for non-skewed coverage reports
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS  "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -O0")
    set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -O0")

    # optional excludes - None needed here
    #    set(COVERAGE_EXCLUDES)

    # importantly, set the path to the gcovr executable that you downladed
    set(GCOVR_PATH "/home/ciaran/miniconda3/bin/gcovr")
    # Works
    setup_target_for_coverage_gcovr_xml(
            NAME TestDoMathCoverageXml
            EXECUTABLE TestDoMath
            DEPENDENCIES TestDoMath DoMath
    )
    # Works
    setup_target_for_coverage_gcovr_html(
            NAME TestDoMathCoverageHtml
            EXECUTABLE TestDoMath
            DEPENDENCIES TestDoMath DoMath
    )
    # This one did not work for me:
    setup_target_for_coverage_lcov(
            NAME TestDoMathCoverageLcov
            EXECUTABLE TestDoMath
            DEPENDENCIES TestDoMath DoMath
    )
endif ()
```

And thats it. Now just build the new targets.

Good luck.

Answer (score 8):

I set up my project 'foo' in the following way. Copied the cmake file from the https://github.com/bilke/cmake-modules/blob/master/CodeCoverage.cmake to a subdirectory 'cmake_modules'. In the CMakeLists.txt file after the `add_executable(foo ...)` I added the following:

```
if(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX)
LIST(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake_modules")
include(CodeCoverage)
APPEND_COVERAGE_COMPILER_FLAGS()
set(COVERAGE_LCOV_EXCLUDES 'dir1/*' 'dir2/*') // this is optional if you want to exclude some directory from the report
SETUP_TARGET_FOR_COVERAGE_LCOV(NAME foo_coverage
                              EXECUTABLE foo
                              DEPENDENCIES foo)
endif()
```

After cmake, build the target
    make 
    make foo_coverage
And open the report with index.html file in the foo_coverage folder in the build folder