# Is there a way to call the "deleting destructor" of a pure virtual class?

Tags: c++, c++11, destructor, gcov, lcov

I'm using C++11 and g++4.8 on Ubuntu Trusty.

Consider this snippet

```
class Parent {
public:
    virtual ~Parent() =  default;
    virtual void f() = 0;
};

class Child: public Parent {
public:
    void f(){}
};
```

Called using

```
{
    Child o;
    o.f();
}
{
    Parent * o  = new Child;
    delete o;
}
{
    Child * o  = new Child;
    delete o;
}
```

I use gcov to generate my code coverage report. It report that the destructor with symbol `_ZN6ParentD0Ev` is never called, while `_ZN6ParentD2Ev` is.

Answer [Dual emission of constructor symbols](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6921295/dual-emission-of-constructor-symbols/6921467#6921467) and [GNU GCC (g++): Why does it generate multiple dtors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6613870/gnu-gcc-g-why-does-it-generate-multiple-dtors/6614369#6614369) reports that `_ZN6ParentD0Ev` is the deleting constructor.

**Is there any case where this "deleting destructor" is called on the `Parent` class ?**

Subsidiary question: if not, is there a way to get the gcov/lcov code coverage tool (used following answer of [Detailed guide on using gcov with CMake/CDash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13116488/detailed-guide-on-using-gcov-with-cmake-cdash)) ignore that symbol in its report ?

Comment: So is the answer "no, there is no way to get coverage of that function?"

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to get gcov to ignore that symbol?

Comment: If I remember well, I just ignored the coverage of the destructor using standard GCOV structured comments

Comment: are you talking about LCOV exclusion markers? http://ltp.sourceforge.net/coverage/lcov/geninfo.1.php

Comment: Ok, yes, I was able to suppress it using `LCOV_EXCL_START` and `LCOV_EXCL_STOP` around the derived class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it's because you have the `Child` object, not `Parent` object.

```
{
    Child o;
    o.f();
} // 1

{
    Parent * o  = new Child;
    delete o;
} // 2

{
    Child * o  = new Child;
    delete o;
} // 3
```

In `// 1`, `o` is destroyed, and the *complete object destructor* of `Child` is called. Since `Child` inherits `Parent`, it'll call the *base object destructor*, which is `_ZN6ParentD2Ev`, of `Parent`.

In `// 2`, `o` is dynamically allocated and deleted, and the *deleting destructor* of `Child` is called. Then, it'll call the *base object destructor* of `Parent`. In both, base object destructor is called.

`// 3` is same. it's just equal to `// 2`, except `o`'s type.

---

I've tested it on cygwin & g++ 4.8.3 & windows 7 x86 SP1. Here's my test code.

```
class Parent
{
public:
    virtual ~Parent() { }
    virtual void f() = 0;
};

class Child : public Parent
{
public:
    void f() { }
};

int main()
{
    {
        Child o;
        o.f();
    }
    {
        Parent * o  = new Child;
        delete o;
    }
    {
        Child * o  = new Child;
        delete o;
    }
}
```

and compile & gcov option:

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage -O0 test.cpp -o test
$ ./test
$ gcov -b -f test.cpp
```

Here's the result.

```
        -:    0:Source:test.cpp
        -:    0:Graph:test.gcno
        -:    0:Data:test.gcda
        -:    0:Runs:1
        -:    0:Programs:1
function _ZN6ParentC2Ev called 2 returned 100% blocks executed 100%
        2:    1:class Parent
        -:    2:{
        -:    3:public:
function _ZN6ParentD0Ev called 0 returned 0% blocks executed 0%
function _ZN6ParentD1Ev called 0 returned 0% blocks executed 0%
function _ZN6ParentD2Ev called 3 returned 100% blocks executed 75%
        3:    4:    virtual ~Parent() = default;
call    0 never executed
call    1 never executed
branch  2 never executed
branch  3 never executed
call    4 never executed
branch  5 taken 0% (fallthrough)
branch  6 taken 100%
call    7 never executed
        -:    5:    virtual void f() = 0;
        -:    6:};
        -:    7:
function _ZN5ChildD0Ev called 2 returned 100% blocks executed 100%
function _ZN5ChildD1Ev called 3 returned 100% blocks executed 75%
function _ZN5ChildC1Ev called 2 returned 100% blocks executed 100%
        7:    8:class Child : public Parent
call    0 returned 100%
call    1 returned 100%
call    2 returned 100%
branch  3 taken 0% (fallthrough)
branch  4 taken 100%
call    5 never executed
call    6 returned 100%
        -:    9:{
        -:   10:public:
function _ZN5Child1fEv called 1 returned 100% blocks executed 100%
        1:   11:    void f() { }
        -:   12:};
        -:   13:
function main called 1 returned 100% blocks executed 100%
        1:   14:int main()
        -:   15:{
        -:   16:    {
        1:   17:        Child o;
        1:   18:        o.f();
call    0 returned 100%
call    1 returned 100%
        -:   19:    }
        -:   20:    {
        1:   21:        Parent * o  = new Child;
call    0 returned 100%
call    1 returned 100%
        1:   22:        delete o;
branch  0 taken 100% (fallthrough)
branch  1 taken 0%
call    2 returned 100%
        -:   23:    }
        -:   24:    {
        1:   25:        Child * o  = new Child;
call    0 returned 100%
call    1 returned 100%
        1:   26:        delete o;
branch  0 taken 100% (fallthrough)
branch  1 taken 0%
call    2 returned 100%
        -:   27:    }
        1:   28:}
```

As you can see, `_ZN6ParentD2Ev`, the base object destructur of `Base`, is called while the others of `Base` are not called.

However, `_ZN5ChildD0Ev`, deleting destructor of `Child`, is called twice and `_ZN5ChildD1Ev`, complete object destructor of `Child`, is called three times, since there's `delete o;` and `Child o;`.

But according my explanation, `_ZN5ChildD0Ev` should be called twice and `_ZN5ChildD1Ev` should be called **once**, shouldn't it? To figure out the reason, I did this:

```
$ objdump -d test > test.dmp
```

Result:

```
00403c88 <__ZN5ChildD0Ev>:
  403c88:   55                      push   %ebp
  403c89:   89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
  403c8b:   83 ec 18                sub    $0x18,%esp
  403c8e:   a1 20 80 40 00          mov    0x408020,%eax
  403c93:   8b 15 24 80 40 00       mov    0x408024,%edx
  403c99:   83 c0 01                add    $0x1,%eax
  403c9c:   83 d2 00                adc    $0x0,%edx
  403c9f:   a3 20 80 40 00          mov    %eax,0x408020
  403ca4:   89 15 24 80 40 00       mov    %edx,0x408024
  403caa:   8b 45 08                mov    0x8(%ebp),%eax
  403cad:   89 04 24                mov    %eax,(%esp)
  403cb0:   e8 47 00 00 00          call   403cfc <__ZN5ChildD1Ev>
  403cb5:   a1 28 80 40 00          mov    0x408028,%eax
  403cba:   8b 15 2c 80 40 00       mov    0x40802c,%edx
  403cc0:   83 c0 01                add    $0x1,%eax
  403cc3:   83 d2 00                adc    $0x0,%edx
  403cc6:   a3 28 80 40 00          mov    %eax,0x408028
  403ccb:   89 15 2c 80 40 00       mov    %edx,0x40802c
  403cd1:   8b 45 08                mov    0x8(%ebp),%eax
  403cd4:   89 04 24                mov    %eax,(%esp)
  403cd7:   e8 a4 f9 ff ff          call   403680 <___wrap__ZdlPv>
  403cdc:   a1 30 80 40 00          mov    0x408030,%eax
  403ce1:   8b 15 34 80 40 00       mov    0x408034,%edx
  403ce7:   83 c0 01                add    $0x1,%eax
  403cea:   83 d2 00                adc    $0x0,%edx
  403ced:   a3 30 80 40 00          mov    %eax,0x408030
  403cf2:   89 15 34 80 40 00       mov    %edx,0x408034
  403cf8:   c9                      leave  
  403cf9:   c3                      ret    
  403cfa:   90                      nop
  403cfb:   90                      nop
```

Yeah, since `_ZN5ChildD0Ev` calls `_ZN5ChildD1Ev`, `_ZN5ChildD1Ev` was called three times. (1 + 2) I guess it's just GCC's implementation - for reduce duplication.

Comment: Does that mean when deleting an object, the only "deleting destructor" called is the one of the final/actual type, and not any other from the inherithance hierarchy ? If so, then obviously it'll never be called on `Parent`.

Answer (score 2):

You can't have Parent objects, so no. It's a GCC oversight that this needless function is generated. The optimizer really should remove it, as it's unused, but I've found that GCC has problems is that area as well.

Answer (score 1):

As ikh has explained, the D0 destructor is needlessly generated (and unusable) when the pure virtual parent class has a virtual destructor.

However, if the pure virtual parent class has a *non-virtual* destructor, you can delete a pointer to the parent type and this *will* invoke the parent's D0 destructor.  Of course, non-virtual destructors in a parent class are rarely desirable or intended, so g++ emits the warning: `[-Wdelete-non-virtual-dtor]`.