# configuring code coverage with cmake

Tags: c++, linux, cmake, code-coverage, gcov

I'm on a linux machine, trying to build a project using cmake that does out of source builds. For code coverage, I looked into gcov and followed a simple tutorial that generate appropriate files for a sample `helloWorld.cpp` program. The only requirement were to compile with `-fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage` flags & link with `-lgcov` flag, which can be done altogether with `-coverage` flag.

Now here comes the tricky part. I have a `CMakeLists.txt` wit contents as shown below:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.8)
project (SomeName)

SET(GCC_COVERAGE_COMPILE_FLAGS "-g -O0 -coverage -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage")
SET(GCC_COVERAGE_LINK_FLAGS    "-coverage -lgcov")
SET( CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS  "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${GCC_COVERAGE_COMPILE_FLAGS}" )
SET( CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS  "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} ${GCC_COVERAGE_LINK_FLAGS}" )

set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin)

include_directories(include)
set(CATCH_HEADER_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/test/catch.hpp)

add_executable(runTest ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/test/test.cpp ${CATCH_HEADER_PATH})
```

So I've included appropriate compile time flags as well as linker flags too and appended them correctly. Another thing to note is `set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin)` line which says that executables will be generated inside **`bin`** directory.

Now everything works as intended except that coverage files aren't generated properly. I follow these steps :

```
mkdir build && cd build
cmake ..
make -j4
./bin/runTest
```

and no other file is generated inside **`bin`** folder. However on more inspection I found out that there is another location **`build/CMakeFiles/runTest.dir/test`** where `test.cpp.o` resides initially and after the final step `./bin/runTest`, two new files - `test.cpp.gcda` & `test.cpp.gcno` are generated.

I've already tried copying `test/test.cpp` to **`build/CMakeFiles/runTest.dir/test`** and running `gcov test.cpp` but it fails stating - `test.gcno:cannot open notes file`

Comment: I've pushed updated CMakeLists.txt for this question [here](https://github.com/agauniyal/rang). anyone can use this repo for quick repro.

Comment: When source files and gcov data files (`.gcno`, `.gcda`) are located in *different* directories, you need to hint `gcov` where it can find them. E.g, you may pass option `-o <object-directory>` to gcov to specify location of data files. Everything other described in your question post works correctly.

Comment: possible dup http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13116488/detailed-guide-on-using-gcov-with-cmake-cdash also check documentation here https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.2/module/CTestCoverageCollectGCOV.html

Comment: @SergeiNikulov 1st link uses lcov on top & 2nd one is much different since it uses CTest and CDash.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A mismatch in gcov and gcc version was making this happen. `gcc` symlink `/usr/bin/gcc` was set to newest `gcc`, same for `g++` but `gcov` in `$PATH` was still pointing to older version of `gcov`.