# Using gcov with CMake step by step

Tags: c++, linux, cmake, code-coverage, gcov

I'm trying to run gcov on a project i'm working on, using [this guide](https://github.com/bilke/cmake-modules/blob/master/CodeCoverage.cmake).

I followed the instruction on the guide and read a lot of posts, including the [detailed guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13116488/detailed-guide-on-using-gcov-with-cmake-cdash) on this site.

But I can't make it work.

The steps I followed are:

1. My main `CMakeLists.txt` of my project is inside a folder called `cmake`. Inside this folder I created another folder called `CMakeModules` and put the `CodeCoverage.cmake` file inside.
2. I added this code to my CMakeLists.txt:

   ```
   set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/CMakeModules)
   if(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX)
   include(CodeCoverage)
   APPEND_COVERAGE_COMPILER_FLAGS()
   SETUP_TARGET_FOR_COVERAGE(NAME coverage 
   EXECUTABLE 
   DEPENDENCIES coverage)
   endif()
   ```
3. I compiled using the commands:

   ```
   cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=DEBUG ../cmake
   # (I'm compiling from a subfolder of the master folder)

   make

   make coverage
   ```
4. I have an error when I run `make coverage` command:

   ```
   [100%] Resetting code coverage counters to zero.
   Processing code coverage counters and generating report.

   Errno architecture (x86_64-linux-thread-multi-4.6.4-301.fc24.x86_64) does not match executable architecture (x86_64-linux-thread-multi-4.12.9-300.fc26.x86_64) at /usr/lib64/perl5/Errno.pm line 11.

   Compilation failed in require at /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/File/Temp.pm line 17.

   BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/File/Temp.pm line 17.

   Compilation failed in require at /usr/bin/lcov line 66.

   BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/bin/lcov line 66.

   CMakeFiles/coverage.dir/build.make:57: set di istruzioni per l'obiettivo "CMakeFiles/coverage" non riuscito

   make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/coverage] Error 255

   CMakeFiles/Makefile2:178: set di istruzioni per l'obiettivo "CMakeFiles/coverage.dir/all" non riuscito

   make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/coverage.dir/all] Errore 2
   CMakeFiles/Makefile2:185: set di istruzioni per l'obiettivo "CMakeFiles/coverage.dir/rule" non riuscito

   make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/coverage.dir/rule] Errore 2

   Makefile:214: set di istruzioni per l'obiettivo "coverage" non riuscito
   make: *** [coverage] Errore 2
   ```

My questions are:

Exactly what should I put into the EXECUTABLE slot? The path to the executable that starts the program?

The Setup of the program can be done just by that line I wrote?

I already tried the solution from other threads on this site, but I can't anything that suggest me how to make this work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `EXECUTABLE` option should define how to run something on your code and generate coverage data.

For instance, it should be the instruction that run all your tests.

If you have test defined using ctest, try something like:

```
SETUP_TARGET_FOR_COVERAGE(NAME coverage 
                          EXECUTABLE ctest)
```

(or `ctest --parallel n` if you have a lot of tests and more than one processor!)
If you have a specific target that run some test, then try something like:

```
SETUP_TARGET_FOR_COVERAGE(NAME coverage 
                          EXECUTABLE make target)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank You Mahnu!
Now it's clear for me! The error was that i was linking the executable of the program, so it wasn't working!