# How to get coverage for tests with CMake and Catch2

Tags: c++, cmake, code-coverage, catch2

I'm trying to print coverage with `lcov` on a `C++` project that is using `Catch2` for tests. I'm able to run my tests and get results. However, I'm unable to get any coverage. This is the error that is shown.

```
Capturing coverage data from .
Found gcov version: 9.3.0
Using intermediate gcov format
Scanning . for .gcda files ...
geninfo: WARNING: no .gcda files found in . - skipping!
Finished .info-file creation
Combining tracefiles.
Reading tracefile coverage.base
lcov: ERROR: no valid records found in tracefile coverage.base
```

My current toolchain is `WSL`. I'm using `Conan` for dependency management. The solution has the following structure:

```
my project/
├─ build/
│  ├─ build files
├─ core/
│  ├─ library files
├─ main/
│  ├─ main runtime
├─ tests/
│  ├─ test runtime/
├─ CMakeLists.txt
```

Each folder has it's `CMakeLists.txt` file and is identified as a target. I'm also using [this CMake Module](https://github.com/bilke/cmake-modules/blob/master/CodeCoverage.cmake) to register a target for coverage.

My root `CMakeLists.txt` looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)
project(my-project)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-O0")

include(build/conanbuildinfo.cmake)
conan_basic_setup()

add_subdirectory(core)

option(BUILD_TESTING "Builds only the test executable." OFF)
option(CODE_COVERAGE "Collect coverage from test library" OFF)

if(BUILD_TESTING)
    enable_testing()
    add_subdirectory(tests)
    add_test(NAME project-tests COMMAND ./bin/tests)

    if(CODE_COVERAGE)
        include(CodeCoverage.cmake)
        append_coverage_compiler_flags()
        setup_target_for_coverage_lcov(NAME coverage EXECUTABLE ./bin/tests BASE_DIRECTORY ../coverage)
    endif()
else()
    add_subdirectory(main)
endif()
```

To get my coverage, I'm using the following commands (on `build/`).

```sh
cmake .. -DCODE_COVERAGE=ON -DBUILD_TESTING=ON -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug
make
make coverage
```

From what I understand, it seems to be missing some files necessary for coverage information, but I don't know how to make them. From what I've looked online, I have all the necessary compiler flags. I can't see what is wrong/missing in here.

Comment: Do you see the relevant coverage flags when you build?

Comment: Do you use one directory, `build`, for all compilations? Then do not forget to `make clean`. Its far better and safe to have different  build directories for different build configurations.

Comment: @StephenNewell I don't see them when I build. I don't see the command that has been executed actually. I see that the coverage module appends the flags to the solution.

Comment: @zkoza I'm new to CMake. If you have any ressources to best practices, I will gladly read them! To answer your question, I've tried to do `make clean` after doing `make`, but it didn't change much.

Comment: I consider myself an intermediate cmake user and learn myself. But please see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13116488/detailed-guide-on-using-gcov-with-cmake-cdash  The answer here, by @AntonArtiukh, is ok in that it is simple and just works. But it is against the spirit of cmake (everything should be as platform-independent as possible). The link shows a more professional solution. Choose whichever suits you better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you forgot to add appropriate flags

```
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS " ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage")
```

Comment: It did the job! I'm not sure to fully understand why though. Thank you for the answer!

Comment: @ges134 without these flags you won't get .gcda files. See this doc, for ex https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/Development/Lcov